# Get element by class at given index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got html looking like this:

```
<main>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="newdiv">
            <input type="text" class="stuff ind">
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
            <button class="add">Add</button>
            <div class="start ind">0</div>
            <div class="creation-time ind">0</div>
            <div class="priv ind">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Some of the elements have additional class 'ind'. And my question is there a way in which I could access those elements by their class and index? For example, I want to get a third element with 'ind' class. I've tried things like `$('.list').find('.ind').eq(3)` but with no luck.

Comment: What you say you tried works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/jhsbsayh/, However `eq(3)` will grab the fourth item as it's zero-based

Comment: Note, though, that if you have multiple `.list` elements, you may not get what you expect.

Comment: Does it make a difference if those elements are dynamically created?

Comment: Depending on your code it could, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is using `.toArray()` method.

- Once all `.ind`s are in an array named `indArray` it is sent through a for loop.
- On each iteration (loop), a `.ind` will be assigned text that corresponds to their own index.
- On each iteration a `.ind` will have red text.
- On the first `.ind` (`indArray[0]`) since it's an input and not a div, it's number is set by `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

So as an array of `.ind`s, you now have easy access by index and class. If you wanted to select the third `.ind` to have a pink background:

- `indArray[2].style.backgroundColor = "pink";`

Note: You're probably already aware that arrays are zero based so `indArray[2]` is the third element of the array.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
     var indArray = $('.ind').toArray();
      
      for(var i = 0; i < indArray.length; i++) {
        indArray[i].innerHTML = i;
        indArray[i].style.color = "red";
        if(i === 0) {
          indArray[i].value = i;
        }
      }
  });
```

```css
main {
  border: 4px dotted black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="newdiv">
      <input type="text" class="stuff ind">
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      <button class="add">Add</button>
      <div class="start ind">0</div>
      <div class="creation-time ind">0</div>
      <div class="priv ind">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your original `$('.list').find('.ind').eq(3)` should work just fine to do exactly what you want to do (are you sure jQuery is loading correctly?), alternatively `$('.list .ind').eq(3)` will also work (less efficient though).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it using a compound CSS selector and then grabbing the 3rd element in the array. So `$('.list .ind').eq(2);`

Here it is working in JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/cirikapewi/edit?html,js,output